# Incorrect captcha error message not showing on previous means form page magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

Here i am using captcha in products view page but in this page captcha error message not showing this captcha error message is showing in home page magento 1.9.

> app/code/local/Ifuturz/Questionanswer/Model

Below code i accessed the session which is started in view.phtml where we are calling directly this form.here session is working fine and it is redirectting to the previous page but error message not showing.

```
public function checkQuestions($observer){
        $formId = 'vendor_form';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired()){
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $word = $this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $sessionaccess= Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
                $url = $sessionaccess->getData("access_value");
                /* $data = explode("index.php/",$url);
                $url =  Mage::getUrl($data[1]); */
                //$url =  Mage::getBaseUrl();
                //$currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
                //$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
public function checkQuestions($observer){
        $formId = 'vendor_form';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired()){
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $word = $this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $sessionaccess= Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
                $url = $sessionaccess->getData("access_value");


                //Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Incorrect CAPTCHA.');
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                exit;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: redirection is working but "Incorrect CAPTCHA" message not showing for false captcha

Comment: @hiteshbalpande I update answer, try that code to show error.

Comment: i added this line of code Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'); but redirection is working but "Incorrect CAPTCHA" message not showing for false captcha

Comment: Actually we are not using layout for captcha directly  we are using html code generated from layout captcha in contacts page and its loading captcha in our form means its working

Comment: thanks sir its worked but some time same code was not working